# Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div> but i don't know what is problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

This error was not occurred until my lastest commit, but today it suddenly happened.
I searched about it for 1 and half hours, but I couldn't find the answer.

this is my code:

```
import { NextPage, Metadata } from 'next'
import Demo from './demo'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: '로그인',
}

const SignIn: NextPage = () => {
    return (
        <Demo />
    )
}

export default SignIn
```

this is signin/page.tsx

```
'use client'
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Demo: NextPage = () => {
    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center py-20'>
          <div className='space-y-14 w-1/2'>
            <div className='flex flex-col items-center space-y-3'>
              <Image src='/img/logo.svg' alt='logo' width={100} height={100} className='w-44' />
              <h1 className='font-bold text-4xl'>로그인</h1>
            </div>
            <div className='text-xl space-y-5'>
              <div className='space-y-2'>
                <p>이메일</p>
                <input type='text' placeholder='이메일 주소를 입력해주세요.' className='border border-gray-300 py-2 px-5 w-full focus:outline-2 focus:outline-cyellow rounded placeholder:text-lg text-lg' />
              </div>
              <div className='space-y-2'>
                <p>비밀번호</p>
                <input type='password' placeholder='비밀번호를 입력해주세요.' className='border border-gray-300 py-2 px-5 w-full focus:outline-2 focus:outline-cyellow rounded placeholder:text-lg text-lg' />
              </div>
              <button className='text-lg bg-cyellow rounded w-full py-2 text-center font-medium hover:opacity-70 transition-all'>로그인</button>
              <div className='text-base text-center space-x-3 text-gray-500'>
                <Link href='/signup' className='hover:text-cyellow hover:underline transition-colors'>회원가입</Link>
                <Link href='/signin/password' className='hover:text-cyellow hover:underline transition-colors'>비밀번호 찾기</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='space-y-5'>
              <div className='relative'>
                <div className='border-t absolute w-full' />
                <div className='relative -top-3 text-center'>
                  <span className='bg-white px-5 text-3xl font-bold'>소셜 로그인</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='flex items-center justify-center space-x-14'>
                {
                  ['google', 'apple', 'facebook'].map((social, i) => <div key={i}>
                    <button className='rounded-full border w-14 h-14 flex items-center justify-center hover:opacity-70 transition-all'>
                      <div className='p-3'>
                        <Image src={`/img/socials/${social}.svg`} alt={social} width={100} height={100} className='img' />
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>)
                }
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Demo
```

this is signin/demo.tsx

Could you teach me what is problem please?

Comment: No, don't post errors as images, don't post code as images, don't host your code externally and ask us to debug it. We are here to help you but not to debug your entire project. Just post the relevant code here, add a minimal snippet or something, just make sure it is here, easy to access, copy and modify so we don't have to type everything across. Would it be easier for your to work with code if they were just images?

Comment: look at the console. you can find a trace of the components hierarchy that throw such an error. this error means that the initial HTML that was created in the client is different from the server's HTML. In this case, a div is expected inside another div which means one div is getting lost inside the client's initial rendering.